# Adding x-logo vendor extension using Swashbuckle Asp.Net Core for ReDoc

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I'm using swagger.json file (generated by Swashbuckle) for ReDoc to display API documentation.

**What I Need:**
 Add `x-logo` vendor extension to swagger json generated using Swashbuckle (`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen` library) so that ReDoc UI shows logo at the top left corner [like this](https://rebilly.github.io/ReDoc/) 
[image]

**Problem:**
I was able to add `x-log` to the swagger.json file but it is added to wrong section of the file. It needs to be inside `info` section.

This is what I have done to add the `x-logo`

- Created a document filter like below

```cs
    public class XLogoDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
        {
            public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
            {
              swaggerDoc.Extensions["x-logo"] = new { url = "https://URL/of/the/logo", altText = "Company Logo" };
            }

        }
```

- Added the filter to `SwaggerDoc` as

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(options => 
{   
  options.DocumentFilter<XLogoDocumentFilter>();

});
```

*Actual*

```
    {
      "swagger": "2.0",
      "info": {
        "version": "v1",
        "title":"Sample REST API"
      },
      "x-logo": {
        "url": "https://rebilly.github.io/ReDoc/petstore-logo.png",
        "altText": "Aimia Logo"
      }
    }
```

*Expected*

```
    {
      "swagger": "2.0",
      "info": {
        "version": "v1",
        "title":"Sample REST API",
        "x-logo": {
          "url": "https://rebilly.github.io/ReDoc/petstore-logo.png",
          "altText": "Aimia Logo"
        }
      },

    }
```

Really appreciate any help or suggestions to have the `x-logo` in the correct section of the swagger.json file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After typing the question I found the solution myself. Instead of adding extension directly to swaggerDoc, add it to swaggerDoc.Info object.

```cs
public class XLogoDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
        {
            public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
            {   
              // need to check if extension already exists, otherwise swagger 
              // tries to re-add it and results in error  
              if (!swaggerDoc.Info.Extensions.ContainsKey("x-logo"))
              {
                 swaggerDoc.Info.Extensions.Add("x-logo", new {
                    url = "https://URL/To/The/Logo",
                    altText = "Logo",
                });
              }           

            }

        }
```

Comment: No longer works in the newest version of SwashBuckle

Answer (score 10):

The newer versions of Swashbuckle support this in the SwaggerDoc setup:

```
c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
{
  Title = ApiDescription,
  Version = "v1",
  Extensions = new Dictionary<string, IOpenApiExtension>
    {
      {"x-logo", new OpenApiObject
        {
           {"url", new OpenApiString("https://blah.com/logo")},
           { "altText", new OpenApiString("The Logo")}
        } 
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

for .NET core 2.2 and higher

```
public class XLogoDocumentFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        // need to check if extension already exists, otherwise swagger 
        // tries to re-add it and results in error  
        if (!swaggerDoc.Info.Extensions.ContainsKey("x-logo"))
            swaggerDoc.Info.Extensions.Add("x-logo", new OpenApiObject
            {
                {"url", new OpenApiString("https://www.petstore.com/assets/images/logo.png")},
                {"backgroundColor", new OpenApiString("#FFFFFF")},
                {"altText", new OpenApiString("PetStore Logo")}
            });
    }

}
```